# The .filter() method is return an empty array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use JavaScript's filter() method to return an array of objects where the objects have a certain value. In my scenario, a user can have a first name, last name, and multiple characters attached to them.

I'm trying to use filter() to return any objects that have characters with at least 100 or more gold but it returns with an empty array. Here's what I wrote:

```js
var users = [{
    firstname: 'Owen',
    lastname: 'Wilson',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 150
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    firstname: 'Vince',
    lastname: 'Vaughan',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 90
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    firstname: 'Ben',
    lastname: 'Stiller',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 200
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  }

];
var minimumGold = element => element.characters.gold >= 100;
var usersWithLotsOfGold = users.filter(minimumGold);
console.log(usersWithLotsOfGold);
// Expected objects [0] and [2]
```

Comment: characters is an array, whereas you are trying to access the gold property by directly calling characters.gold

Comment: `element.characters` is an array, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check each character in the `characters` array. One approach is to use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this:

```js
const users = [{firstname:'Owen',lastname:'Wilson',characters:[{race:'dwarf',level:80,gold:150},{race:'dark elf',level:75,gold:50},{race:'human',level:70,gold:75}]},{firstname:'Vince',lastname:'Vaughan',characters:[{race:'dwarf',level:80,gold:90},{race:'dark elf',level:75,gold:50},{race:'human',level:70,gold:75}]},{firstname:'Ben',lastname:'Stiller',characters:[{race:'dwarf',level:80,gold:200},{race:'dark elf',level:75,gold:50},{race:'human',level:70,gold:75}]}];
const minimumGold = element => element.characters.some(
  character => character.gold >= 100
);
const usersWithLotsOfGold = users.filter(minimumGold);

console.log(usersWithLotsOfGold);
```

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't see the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`element.characters` and it doesnot have a property `gold`. If you want to check every element you can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on `elements.characters`.

```js
var users = [{
    firstname: 'Owen',
    lastname: 'Wilson',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 150
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    firstname: 'Vince',
    lastname: 'Vaughan',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 90
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    firstname: 'Ben',
    lastname: 'Stiller',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 200
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  }

];

var minimumGold = element => element.characters.some(x => x.gold >= 100 );
    var usersWithLotsOfGold = users.filter(minimumGold);
console.log(usersWithLotsOfGold)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `element.characters` is an array, so it doesn't have a property name gold, so `element.characters.gold >= 100` will always return false.

Instead, you should run another array method on the `element.characters` property. And since I'm assuming you want users that have at least one character with 100 gold, we are going to use the `[].some` method.

```js
var users = [{
    firstname: 'Owen',
    lastname: 'Wilson',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 150
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    firstname: 'Vince',
    lastname: 'Vaughan',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 90
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    firstname: 'Ben',
    lastname: 'Stiller',
    characters: [{
        race: 'dwarf',
        level: 80,
        gold: 200
      },
      {
        race: 'dark elf',
        level: 75,
        gold: 50
      },
      {
        race: 'human',
        level: 70,
        gold: 75
      }
    ]
  }

];
var usersWithLotsOfGold = users.filter((user) => user.characters.some((character) => character.gold >= 100));
console.log(usersWithLotsOfGold);
// Expected objects [0] and [2]
```